# Redash issue with Google Sheets

Tags: redash

I have `redash` setup and I am able to connect to gsheet datasource but when I attempt a select query

```
select * from 1YaipA_nhUq5zl37EZ9tFa32qc4kgF1cMlo41ch1lcF4
```

I am getting

```
Error running query: Spreadsheet (select * from 1YaipA_nhUq5zl37EZ9tFa32qc4kgF1cMlo41ch1lcF4) not found. Make sure you used correct id.
```

I have shared the sheet with the service account ID and it's a simple sheet I am using for testing.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YaipA_nhUq5zl37EZ9tFa32qc4kgF1cMlo41ch1lcF4/edit?usp=sharing
I know I have had this working in the past, must be missing something simple.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After checking Redash's implementation of [Google Sheet query runner](https://github.com/getredash/redash/blob/master/redash/query_runner/google_spreadsheets.py), in order to access the sheet, the query format should be a one-liner:

```
SpreadsheetID|SheetNumber
```

In your case, that would be:

```
1YaipA_nhUq5zl37EZ9tFa32qc4kgF1cMlo41ch1lcF4
```

to access the first worksheet by default. Alternatively, you may want to be more specific:

```
1YaipA_nhUq5zl37EZ9tFa32qc4kgF1cMlo41ch1lcF4|1
```

for accessing second worksheet.

Keep in mind that Redash don't execute your query on-the-fly, rather it will load the whole worksheet before you can make further processing according to the [official documentation](https://redash.io/help/data-sources/querying-a-google-spreadsheet).

After data loading, you should be able to see something like this:

[image]

It simply means that Redash had loaded your data (in this case, 1,962 rows) and you can start to make some visualizations. Cheers!